# According to Protestant interpretations of the Bible, is there justification for “disliking somebody”?

Tags: biblical-basis, protestantism, christian-living, relationships

We know that if we hate a brother we are a murderer at heart:

> “We know that we have passed from death to life, because we love the
> brethren. He who does not love his brother abides in death. ***Whoever
> hates his brother is a murderer***, and you know that no murderer has
> eternal life abiding in him.” ‭‭I John‬ ‭3:14-15‬

Hatred is different than “**disliking**” someone.  Hatred can entail such animosity that things escalate beyond peace, but disliking can be of a more modest nature in terms of behavior.  I wonder if disliking and hatred are the same?

**Q: Is there any biblical justification for disliking somebody?  (Put another way): Is it a sin to “dislike” another person?**

Answer (score 2):

The Bible doesn't pretend that Christians like everyone equally. Instead there will be people we like a lot and get along with, and others who annoy and frustrate us, even people we can't cooperate with in Gospel work.

When Jesus teaches about hospitality he points out that true hospitality is not to host dinner parties for our friends but for those who can't or won't ever reciprocate. Considering that most of us have friends who are poor or have some sort of disability, I take it that the really defining characteristic of hospitality is to care and provide for people who we don't particularly like spending time with.

> Luke 14:12-14: Then Jesus said to his host, “When you give a luncheon or dinner, do not invite your friends, your brothers or sisters, your relatives, or your rich neighbors; if you do, they may invite you back and so you will be repaid. But when you give a banquet, invite the poor, the crippled, the lame, the blind, and you will be blessed. Although they cannot repay you, you will be repaid at the resurrection of the righteous.

The NT frequently describes the fruit of the Spirit, or Godly character traits as involving patience, forbearance, and forgiveness, which are to be directed not just to non-believers but also to our fellow Christian brothers and sisters:

> Galatians 5:22-23: But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, forbearance, kindness, goodness, faithfulness, gentleness and self-control. Against such things there is no law.

> Ephesians 4:2: Be completely humble and gentle; be patient, bearing with one another in love.

> Colossians 3:12-13: Therefore, as God’s chosen people, holy and dearly loved, clothe yourselves with compassion, kindness, humility, gentleness and patience. Bear with each other and forgive one another if any of you has a grievance against someone. Forgive as the Lord forgave you.

And in Acts 15 we see an example of Paul refusing to take Mark with him because he felt betrayed by him, which led to a dispute between Paul and Barnabas that was so severe that those two stopped working together.

> Acts 15:37-40: Barnabas wanted to take John, also called Mark, with them, but Paul did not think it wise to take him, because he had deserted them in Pamphylia and had not continued with them in the work. They had such a sharp disagreement that they parted company. Barnabas took Mark and sailed for Cyprus, but Paul chose Silas and left, commended by the believers to the grace of the Lord.